# selecting an element in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)
a
[[0, 1]
[2, 3]]
a[  a==[0, 1] ][0] = 1
```

Expecting `a = [[1, 1], [2, 3]]` but 'a' didnt change. what underly this problem. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to assign to a copy of the array, not a view, hence the`ndarray` remains unchanged.

One way would be to use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
replace_with = np.vstack([np.ones(a.shape[0]), a[:,1]])
np.where((a==[0,1]).all(1)[:,None], replace_with, a)

array([[1., 1.],
       [2., 3.]])
```

---

Here `replace_with` is an `ndarray` with ones in the first column, and the content of `a` on the second, since it seems like that is what you're trying to do:

```
print(replace_with)

array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 3.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into `a==[0, 1]` you'll find out that it returns a matrix of

```py
array([[False,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

already. So what you need is only:

```py
a = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)
a[a==[0,1]]=1
a
# array([[1, 1],
#        [2, 3]])
```